# Changing VBA ADODB Connection String, Need To Be More Specific

Tags: oracle, vba, excel, adodb

I have a working excel macro that connects using the following connection type:

```
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    cn.Open ( _
    "User ID=userid" & _
    ";Password=pass" & _
    ";Data Source=blank.blank.com" & _
    ";Provider=MSDAORA.1")
```

I can connect in one part of my network but when I try to use the same macro on another computer I can no longer connect. My thought is there is a networking issue and I need to be "more specific". So after some googling I've come across other data connection strings that utilize IP and port name.

```
Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};
Server=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=199.199.199.199)(PORT=1523))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=dbName)));
Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Coming from https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-odbc-for-oracle/

Following Microsofts [documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819) then I get the following:

```
With cn
    .Provider = "MSDAORA.1"
    .ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};" & _
                        "Server=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=1.1.1.1)(PORT=xxxx))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=DB)));" & _
                        "Uid=userid;Pwd=pass;"
    .Open
End With
```

However I get an error: `ORA-12560 TNS:Protocol adapter error`

Some solutions indicate that I should restart the database, but it's running! I connect to it just fine the other way.

Does anyone have a better way of connecting "more specifically" that might help my networking problem or might be able to help me fix up my new way of connecting?

Answer (score 0):

I have always used the option you originally used.  The fact that it works on one machine and does not work on another indicates to me that you do not have the MSDAORA driver installed on the second computer.  The machine requires that the ODBC driver exists on the machine for your code to function.

Go to ODBC and make sure you can create a test connection via the ODBC panel on the second machine to make sure ODBC is functional for the MSDAORA driver.

I see there is no test connection when using Microsoft ODBC for Oracle. There is for the Oracle driver. One way to test it is to open MS Access and create a linked table, using the Microsoft ODBC connection you created. It will prompt you for a password and if it succeeds you will link the table, and know it is working, or it will give you an ODBC error, and you will know it is not.

Or you could use the Oracle driver, which would require installing the Oracle Client driver, and changing your connection information to reflect that driver instead of the MS one.

Comment: If you could provide a bit of detail on testing the connection I'd appreciate it. Googling it now as we speak. But also I thought that by adding Microsoft ActiveX References to the macro on Excel would take care of that?

Comment: I can't seem to find the "test connection" on the ODBC panel after creating the connection. If it accepts and shows on the panel after creation does that mean the test was successful?

Comment: Hmmm...  I see there is no test connection when using Microsoft ODBC for Oracle.  There is for the Oracle driver.  One way to test it is to open MS Access and create a linked table, using the Microsoft ODBC connection you created.  It will prompt you for a password and if it succeeds you will link the table or it will give you an ODBC error.

Comment: So I've discovered the other computer doesn't even show the administrative tools option on the computer.... I can't try setting up the test connection and then use the Access way of testing as you suggest (this worked on the "good" computer). Any other thoughts other than the other PC is on lockdown?

Comment: What you have looks correct.  The ODBC driver is probably not installed.  I have no other solutions given you cannot test the ODBC.  But if it works on your machine and so does the testing of the ODBC, then if probably is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

cn.Open ( _
  "User ID=userid" & _
  ";Password=pass" & _
  ";Data Source=blank.blank.com" & _
  ";Provider=MSDAORA.1")
```